# angularjs $log service performance and possible removal from production

Tags: angularjs, performance

Wondering if logging extensively could cause performance hit in the browser,since we have a lot of code and developers are logging extensively.

Is there an angular way to remove angular js $logs  from production code ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$logProvider. Why are they logging so much? If the goal is debugging, they should learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: just disable logging in production `$logProvider.debugEnabled(false);`

Comment: This will limit the logging to debug level. But I want to remove the log statements from the js itself. Should there be any code that would do it , like there are js compressors. I know people from java background don't used to it :) They just want to log.

Comment: I think your best option is to create a wrapper for $log which you can turn off based on environment config setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), you can minify your code and, in the process, [remove some sections of it](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#conditional-compilation).

> You can use the --define (-d) switch in order to declare global variables that UglifyJS will assume to be constants (unless defined in scope). For example if you pass --define DEBUG=false then, coupled with dead code removal UglifyJS will discard the following from the output:
>
> ```
> if (DEBUG) {
>     console.log("debug stuff");
> }
> ```

I have the feeling that your developers are abusing logs though, and should probably use their debugger more instead of logging.